# insert image with php in the project end print path

Tags: php, image, file, printing, upload

I want to load in an image using php I select from a PC. The file is loaded but within the project folder and not in the folder that I stated.

```
<?php

//dictetion files
$uploaddir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\immagini';

$userfile_tmp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];


$userfile_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];




if (move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir , $userfile_name)) {

  print "File inviato con successo. Ecco alcune informazioni:\n";
  print_r($_FILES);
}else{

  print "Upload NON valido! Alcune informazioni:\n"; 
  print_r($_FILES);
}

?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but according to the documentation `move_uploaded_file()` accepts only _two_ arguments...

Answer (score 0):

Connect the $uploaddir and $userfile_name into one str like this:

```
  if (move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir . $userfile_name)) {

    print "File inviato con successo. Ecco alcune informazioni:\n";
    print_r($_FILES);
  }else{

    print "Upload NON valido! Alcune informazioni:\n";
    print_r($_FILES);
  }
```

see expample #1 from documentation for more info [php.net documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

first, use relative path instead.

So change:

```
$uploaddir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\immagini';
```

with

```
$uploaddir = 'upload/immagini';
```

then your code will be something like

```
$uploaddir = 'upload/immagini';
$userfile_tmp = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$userfile_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];


$path = $uploaddir . $userfile_name;

if (move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $path)) {
  print "File inviato con successo. Ecco alcune informazioni:\n";
  print_r($_FILES);
}else{
  print "Upload NON valido! Alcune informazioni:\n"; 
  print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line with move_uploaded_file to

```
move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $uploaddir.$userfile_name)
```

Should do the job.